# How to cancel a SQL Server command from ASP.NET web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a standard ASP.NET web page. It issues a query, using Ajax, to a SQL Server, and returns a table of results. The problem is, sometimes this table of results is very large and the query takes too long. (I don't have control over the SQL, this happens via a stored procedure.)

Is there a way to have a "Cancel Request" button on the page, so that when the user clicks the button the query on the SQL server is killed? If so, how would I do that? (I am new to ASP.NET/C#, but understand the architecture of web requests.) Thanks.

Comment: You would have to use an ajax pattern-- the request would be via JavaScript and then there are at least 2 places to cancel/timeout-- once for the JS XMLHTTPRequest and in the ado.net connection & command.

Comment: @MatthewMartin Nah this is asp.net ajax probably.  So it looks a little more like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163380.aspx .  It's a lot easier to do in jquery / ajax I think.

Comment: There is no way to do this without AJAX. Request 1-- I call SlowQuery.aspx. I can send no more commands until that page returns. If you fire up a new thread and return early, IIS offers no guarantee that the thread will survive. Request 2-- (we never get here) is the 1st opportunity to cancel anything, but either request 1 is over (and took 1/2 hr) or it runs in an independent thread which IIS will kill. Another AJAX free solution is to use a library like HangFire. MS in 4.5 or so has a build in solution, I forget the name.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z_Qqnq8pI8

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

Create the connection, and place it in a Dictionary, with a Guid.ToString() as key.
Run the query and return the key to your webpage, and save it somewhere.

If the query finishes the execution ok:

```
Find the connection, close it, and remove it from the dictionary.
```

If the user click on cancel query:

```
Send an ajax request to the web server with the key you saved.
Find the connection, close it, and remove it from the dictionary.
```

Make sure of locking the dictionary.

Make sure of catching exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that would be extremely difficult to do, because you would need to know the specific spid for the exact request that issued the long running request.  Something that will be coming from the same user as many more valid requests (if your site is set up like most).

Comment: Guys, closing a connection with a long running query isn't going to end the query on the DB server.   It's just going to make it have no connection to respond on when it tries.

The original poster wants to kill the query on the SQL server.  To do that requires a kill command for the exact spid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same thing, but I'd like to offer some corrections to the above statements. The guy who said finding a SPID is difficult is incorrect. I've just implemented a system where when certain long running stored procedures run, they put (or update) a record into a table that I store that contains SPIDs, the User running the report, some report information, and the date started. Using @@SPID within the stored procedure gets me the SPID that I store in the table.
Also, the connection closing not ending the query is correct, you need a KILL statement.